# selecting factors from a list without replacement

Tags: r

I am writing a script that would automate a mock sports draft given a pool of players to choose from and roster limits for each position.

How would I structure such a script if I have three teams drafting from the following data frame?

Team 1 is using a different ranking than Teams 2 and 3, which are using the consensus; each team will draft one "QB" and one "RB" and each player may only be drafted once (without replacement).

In my mind, the output would be a single data frame.

```
players <- c("Dan Marino", "Tony Dorsett", "Joe Montana", "John Elway",
 "Jim Brown", "Barry Sanders")
position <- c("QB", "RB", "QB", "QB", "RB", "RB")
Team1_rank <- c(2,4,5,6,3,1)
consensus_rank <- c(1,6,3,5,2,4)
player_pool <- data.frame(players, position, Team1_rank, consensus_rank)

            players position Team1_rank consensus
1    Dan Marino       QB          2         1
2  Tony Dorsett       RB          4         6
3   Joe Montana       QB          5         3
4    John Elway       QB          6         5
5     Jim Brown       RB          3         2
6 Barry Sanders       RB          1         4
```

Comment: Add a column (boolean) for whether or not the player has been drafted yet. Then on each team's turn they pick the highest ranked (by their ranking column) player for which `drafted` is not TRUE. Stick it in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sample rows of the dataframe, use sample() on the i index, ie

```
player_pool[sample(6,6), ]
```

will randomly reshuffle the dataframe. If you want only a specific number of each type of player, I would divide the dataframe first into separate player types and then order on each one. You can also specify probability of each pick in sample() (see ?sample)

If you want the list to decrease over time you can set

```
player_pool <- player_pool[sample(nrow(player_pool),nrow(player_pool)),]

pick <- player_pool[1,]

player_pool <- player_pool[2:nrow(player_pool),]
```

in a loop.

Comment: The loop is great! So I understand, the pick is the first row in the data.frame, and then you create a new data.frame with the name, but this time with rows 2:n ? What if don't want to randomly sample the list? In my example, Teams 1-3 know which player they want to take next based on player availability. Is there a way to sample non-randomly?

Comment: You can set the probabilities of each pick inside the sample function `sample(nrow(player_pool),nrow(player_pool), prob = c(.5,.2,....))` Would you mind checking off the answer as a solution if it solves your problem?